# A pure non-UI non-Java FX thread still getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, javafx

I saw many examples of errors involving "Not on FX application thread" and in all the examples I checked, it was always because one was trying to update a UI element from a non-FX tread.  However, in my example, I am getting an error from a thread that has no JAVAFX nor UI code.

The high level summary of my code is that from the controller, I am starting a Task that executes a method anal1.intializeFileList() which is a pure calculation routine with no UI commands, as mentioned above.  It only changes static observable variables in a class called Stats.  These variables are binded to UI elements. Thus, the pure non-UI method communicates to the UI via the variables in the Stats class. I have used this successfully for updating 3 different ProgressBars and enabling and disabling a button and it has worked flawlessly.  I decided to use the same methodology to simply update the text of a Label called initLabel. I do it only twice (and therefore I feel it is much less intense than the updating of the ProgressBars and enabling buttons) and it generates the error "Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-3".

Any ideas why this error is happening, given that my thread is a non-UI and non-JAVAFX tread? How can I prevent the error from happening?

Here are the relevant declarations in my Controller:

```
@FXML
    private ProgressBar populateProgress;

    @FXML
    private ProgressBar sortProgress;

    @FXML
    private ProgressBar dispoProgress;

    @FXML
    private Label initLabel;
```

Here is the non-UI task declared in the Controller:

```
Task<Void> startAnal = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                anal1.intializeFileList();
                return null;
            }
        };
```

Here is the starting of the task

```
 new Thread(startAnal).start();
```

Here are my bindings in the Controller. Note all of the UI's work and all the bindings work except the one associated with initLabel on the last line!

```
@FXML
    public void initialize() {

        // Do bindings
        
        startButton.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> {
            // condition for not being able to start analysis
            int bits012 = 1 | (1 <<1) | (1<<2);
            if (Stats.canStart.getValue() != bits012)
            {
                // can not start because dir's not entered or analysis running
                return true;
            }
            else {
                // valid to start and all dir's entered and analysis is not running
                return false;
            }
        },Stats.canStart));

        populateProgress.progressProperty().bind(Stats.populate);
        sortProgress.progressProperty().bind(Stats.sort);
        dispoProgress.progressProperty().bind((Stats.dispo));
        initLabel.textProperty().bind(Stats.status);
    }
```

Here are some declarations in the Stats class:

```
 static SimpleDoubleProperty populate =  new SimpleDoubleProperty(0.00);
    static SimpleDoubleProperty sort = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0.00);
    static SimpleDoubleProperty dispo = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0.00);
    
    static SimpleIntegerProperty canStart = new SimpleIntegerProperty(1<<2);
    static SimpleBooleanProperty cancel = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
    static SimpleStringProperty status = new SimpleStringProperty("Please Enter Directory options");
```

Here the first (of 2 total) places where the exception is generated (at the line containing Stats.status.set):

```
        Stats.sort.set(0.00);
        Stats.dispo.set(0.00);
        Stats.status.set("Analysis is running");
        // set not running to false
        int running = Stats.canStart.get()&(~(1<<2));
        Stats.canStart.set(running);
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-3
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:291)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:446)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$3.onProposedChange(Parent.java:474)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:113)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:108)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.updateChildren(LabeledSkinBase.java:272)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.lambda$new$11(LabeledSkinBase.java:220)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.LambdaMultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.lambda$new$1(LambdaMultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:181)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(StringPropertyBase.java:104)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:111)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase$Listener.invalidated(StringPropertyBase.java:231)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:136)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(StringPropertyBase.java:104)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:111)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:145)
    at dirComparer/sample.fileDB.intializeFileList(fileDB.java:371)
    at dirComparer/sample.Controller$1.call(Controller.java:299)
    at dirComparer/sample.Controller$1.call(Controller.java:296)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1425)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Comment: I'm not really a JavaFX programmer, but from the stack trace I think the 'observable' nature of the variables is the key. Changing the variable appears to trigger an event and a registered listener that attempts to update the UI, within the context of the thread you're setting it from.

Comment: In JavaFX, listeners and (by extension) bindings are notified on the thread that caused the invalidation and/or change-in-value.

Comment: Thank you. I guess you are saying my non-JAVAFX thread effects a reaction by the FX thread and thus induces a "Not on FX application thread" error? Any recommendation on how to fix this?

Comment: [mcve] please.. _Any recommendation on how to fix_ don't bind ui-related properties to anything that's modified on another thread :) unrelated: static scope is nearly always wrong

Comment: "_effects a reaction by the FX thread_" – Hmm... no, unless you mean something other than what I'm interpreting. There's no "reaction" by the FX thread here. You're modifying something on the background thread which, via one or more listeners, eventually causes an interaction with the UI. That all occurs on the background thread, and therein lies the problem. You must never interact with the UI, directly **or indirectly**, on a background thread. The fix is hinted at by kleopatra. If you need more help I suggest creating and subsequently providing a [mre].

Comment: All this advice is very helpful and should allow me to finish my project. To avoid major changes to my code, I would like to run several Tasks sequentially. Any quick tips on how to do it? I would like the next Task to start as soon as possible after the previous Task finishes. I did a search for this question but did not find answers that seemed directly applicable.